# Production vs Dev API call being redirected to front end

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I understand this is very vague but hopefully I'll update this so that it's sufficient as folks ask questions.

We have a DEV and PROD apache server. Our simple get API call works in PROD. You call the API and data is returned (in a json format).

Now our DEV server has the same Apache configuration with identical rewrite conditions, however when calling the DEV API, the user is redirected to the front end application (written in angular).

```
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} /api/.* [OR]
    #L(ast) flag, if this rule is used stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules
    RewriteRule ^ - [L] #for all matching, pass the existing path through unmodified

    # If above rule did not direct to an existing document, default to index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Since the apache config files are identical, I'm confused why the user is redirected in DEV. I expect the API call in DEV to return data in json format similar to PROD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the routing had to be changed from one server to another